# i have error on strptime does not match format

Tags: python, datetime

I tried to convert string to datetime object:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
dates_number = ['1','2','5','6','7','8','9','12','13','14','15','16','28','29','30',]
dates = []
for i in dates_number:
    dates.append('2022-09-{}'.format(i))
datess= []
for i in dates:
    i=datetime.strptime(i,'%y-%m-%d').date()
    datess.append(i)
print(datess)
```

But I've got this error:

```
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_26240/2225567370.py in <module>
      1 datess= []
      2 for i in dates:
----> 3     i=datetime.strptime(i,'%y-%d-%m')
      4     datess.append(i)
      5 print(datess)

~\anaconda3\lib\_strptime.py in _strptime_datetime(cls, data_string, format)
    566     """Return a class cls instance based on the input string and the
    567     format string."""
--> 568     tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
    569     tzname, gmtoff = tt[-2:]
    570     args = tt[:6] + (fraction,)

~\anaconda3\lib\_strptime.py in _strptime(data_string, format)
    347     found = format_regex.match(data_string)
    348     if not found:
--> 349         raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
    350                          (data_string, format))
    351     if len(data_string) != found.end():

ValueError: time data '2022-09-1' does not match format '%y-%d-%m'
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the correct format to `strptime` it's `%Y-%m-%d`

```
for i in dates:
    i=datetime.strptime(i,'%Y-%m-%d').date()
    #                       ^ updated here 
    datess.append(i)
```

[Reference to the format](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime)

```
%y  Year without century as a zero-padded decimal number.   00, 01, ..., 99
%Y  Year with century as a decimal number.  2013, 2019 etc.
```